# Why do we call 'regular representation' to be 'regular'?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, representation-theory

I am reading representation theory for groups. In this, I have started reading 'regular representation' of a group. I would like to know why do we call 'regular representation' to be 'regular'? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do we call groups 'groups'?

Comment: Since every representation $ \phi : G \longrightarrow GL(V)$ is a homomorphism. In what sense, $\phi$ have regularity property?

Comment: It's true, it would be more descriptive, and not much more trouble, to say "right translation representation of $G$ on $L^2(G)$" or "left translation representation... " or something similar... and on some occasions I do so, rather than use that opaque-but-standard terminology. For that matter, on infinite groups $G$, maybe with topologies, it's ambiguous what space of functions we might want. $L^2$? Continuous? Continuous compactly-supported? Smooth functions on a Lie group?

Comment: In particular, if we have $V=L^2(G)$  where $G$ being infinite like $\mathbb{R}$ and representation is left regular, given by $[L_g (f)](x)=f(g^{-1}x)$. Then what can we say about its regularity?